# npm install gives different output on 2 computers with identical config

Tags: npm, npm-install, aurelia

I have 2 computers. Same configuration.

- Windows version 11
- Node.js version 14.17.1
- npm version 6.14.13
- Typescript version 4.5.5

I have a **package.json** file. When I execute **npm install** the output log is different on the 2 computers. Of course the generated **node_modules** folders are different as well. The difference is highlighted in green below.

Only on the second computer I have the highlighted output. I would like to understand why this difference? Of course there is something for explaining that difference and it can help me to solve the issue I got when I build my app.

[image]

Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "gaffeweb",
  "description": "An Aurelia client application.",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "???",
    "url": "???"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@flowjs/flow.js": "^2.11.2",
    "ag-grid-aurelia": "^20.2.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.2.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.0.0",
    "aurelia-animator-css": "^1.0.4",
    "aurelia-binding": "2.1.7",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "2.3.3",
    "aurelia-breeze": "^2.2.0",
    "aurelia-dialog": "^1.1.0",
    "aurelia-i18n": ">=2.3.2",
    "aurelia-materialize-bridge": "1.2.5",
    "aurelia-templating": "^1.10.1",
    "aurelia-typed-observable-plugin": "^0.4.2",
    "aurelia-validation": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3",
    "breeze-client": "^1.7.2",
    "i18next": "^6.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
    "jstree": "^3.3.7",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "metro-dist": "^3.0.18",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6",
    "select2": "^4.0.5",
    "svgxuse": "^1.2.6",
    "text": "github:requirejs/text#latest",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "trumbowyg": "^2.13.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/breeze": "^1.6.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.6",
    "@types/materialize-css": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/select2": "^4.0.47",
    "aurelia-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "aurelia-testing": "^1.0.0",
    "aurelia-tools": "^2.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
    "debounce": "^1.2.0",
    "event-stream": "^3.3.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-changed-in-place": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-shell": ">=0.6.5",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
    "gulp-tslint": "^8.1.3",
    "gulp-typescript": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1",
    "html-minifier": "^3.5.20",
    "merge2": "^1.2.3",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "through2": "^2.0.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "vinyl-fs": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get when you try and build the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure you have the same conditions on both machines, you can try, for testing, to clear the [npm cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-cache) on both machine (`npm cache clean --force`), and to list the globally installed npm packages, to check they are the same on both machines (`npm list -g --depth=0`).
This assumes the same Node.js and npm versions on both machines, as you mentioned.

Then reinstall node modules:

```bash
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```

That should force a fresh installation of all dependencies.

Make sure both machines have the same relevant environment variables set, and the same [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/config) (`npm config list`)
Also, make sure the file systems are the same and that there are no permission issues with the directories where npm is attempting to install packages.

For your specific issue, you can start by focusing on the `es5-ext` package and its [postinstall script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/scripts). I do not see any [obvious recent issue](https://github.com/medikoo/es5-ext/issues?q=is%3Aissue+postinstall).
Try and temporarily remove `es5-ext` from your dependencies to confirm if it is the source of the inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions, I was able to find some differences between the 2 computers and fix my issue. I had to upgrade some packages and typings as well.

Comment: @Bronzato Well done, good catch! What differences did you spot?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot to go on in your question.

Things you might try:

If you’re not using `package-json.lock` then enable it on the good machine, run another build and then copy it over to other machine.

Another thing that can sometime help, is to delete `node-modules` and `package-json.lock`. Then rerun `npm install`.

Finally you’re running a pretty old version of Node. Have you tried upgrading it? Perhaps by using `nvm` so you can easily switch between versions.